# input loses focus when editing value. Using ngFor and ngModel. Angular5

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular5

I have a simple list that binds two-way to a parameter **hero** in **hero.component.ts**.

Though **when I start typing in the input field it loses focus** and I have to click it again. What am I supposed to do in order to allow the user edit the input value without the input field loses target?

```
 <li *ngFor="let power of hero.powers; let i = index">
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.powers[i]"/>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Using trackBy function of angular fixes the issue.

[live example showing it](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zwnges?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<div>
   <li *ngFor="let power of hero.powers; let i = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <input [(ngModel)]="hero.powers[i]"/>
   </li>
</div>
```

component file

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;  
}
```

Comment: Yeah I know it happens when it updates :) . Though I do not know how I am supposed to list my attributes with two way binding and still be able to edit them without the input field refreshing.

Comment: Assuming hero.powers is an array, there should really be no difference between power and hero.powers[index]. They would refer to the same object.

Comment: @Sebbe then try trackBy function of angular.

Comment: @Sebbe Updated the answer.

Comment: @FranklinPious Great! Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try using `trackBy:trackByFn` in your ngFor, by using it prevent angular to recreate your DOM and it will keep track of changes

see this tutorial [here](https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

Answer (score 0):

In html:

```
<div *ngFor="let a of a[]; let index = index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

In TS:

```
trackByFn(index, item) {   return index; }
```