# Wrong input value when using ngFor and ngModel and an Array

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use ngFor to create inputs, then when I type in a value, both the current and the latter input get the typed in value.

```
<div *ngFor="let val of selectionValues; index as valIndex">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectionValues[valIndex]" />
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="removeSelectionValue(valIndex)">remove</button>
</div>
```

The expected input values are:

(1)
(blank)
(blank)

then

(1)
(2)
(blank)

but this is what I get when I type in:

(1)
(1)
(blank)

then

(1)
(2)
(2)

**Later I observed that the input loses focus when I type in.**

Comment: What is the intended functionality ? That the latter input does not get the input as well ?

Comment: @Zze the inputs should be "1", blank, blank, updated the Q

Answer (score 2):

So I had to use `trackBy` in `ngFor`

Ref URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50139592/1922314

```html
<div *ngFor="let val of selectionValues; index as valIndex; trackBy: trackByFn">
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]="selectionValues[valIndex]" />
  <button mat-button color="primary" (click)="removeSelectionValue(valIndex)">remove</button>
</div>
```

```js
trackByFn(index, item) {
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a quick working solution on stackblitz. 
You may want to try it
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wztqj3

incase if you are still having the issue, please share the ts based additions you have made